# missing UnitTestFramework in visualstudio2017

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, uwp, visual-studio-2017, visualstudio.testtools

I updated VisualStudio from 2015 to 2017.
When i try to launch UWP unit tests, it seems that `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework` does not exists (it gives me an error).
I tried with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` and project builds and run but it does not execute my tests.
How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-members-in-unit-tests

Comment: What are the errors that are produced when the reference is Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework? Can you enable diagnostic build output by going to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run and set "MSBuild project build output verbosity:" to "Diagnostic". When you do that, if you can copy and share the output (to some cloud storage) what will help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with a complete reinstall of visualstudio.

Answer (score 0):

@scriptfx: What version of VS 2017 are you on? Would be great if we can see what error you are hitting. The sdk `MSTestFramework.Universal` should be pointing to a 15.0 version in the build logs.

On a side note you could also upgrade to the new default framework in VS 2017 - MSTest V2. More details here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/06/17/taking-the-mstest-framework-forward-with-mstest-v2/

Comment: I'm sorry to answer just now... I resolved it with a complete reinstall of visualstudio.